# Postgres: convert a column to JsonB

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that has a column is storing data in this format.

```
    {"id"=>619681447963, 
     "variant_id"=>5708282527771, 
     "title"=>"Bike", 
     "quantity"=>1}
```

The column is of type `character varying` and i need to convert it to a jsonb column.

i understand that the current data isn't in json format, and i need to convert the `=>` to `:` i can't figure out an efficient way of doing this. Can someone give me some advice. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH test(col) AS (
SELECT '{"id"=>619681447963, 
     "variant_id"=>5708282527771, 
     "title"=>"Bike", 
     "quantity"=>1}'::text
)
SELECT replace(col, '=>', ':')::jsonb
FROM test
```

you can [`replace`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html) the `=>` to `:`, and cast it to jsonb

Comment: Thanks this was useful but it seems like i have a bunch of other things that don't let me convert to jsonb. I'm going to have to convert it on ruby probably.